# How to see object count in blender

Tags: python, scripting

I need to find a way to see object count by name in Blender.
I use blender to design exhibition stands and use an asset manager with furniture and construction materials. I would like to find a way to see count of objects in my scene, for example, I have 10 chairs, 5 tables, 5 lamps etc and I want to see it like this:
Chair - 10,
Table - 5,
Lamp - 5,
...,
Object # - X pcs.

Is thera a way to do this? I am absolute zero with python code, so I would appreciate any and all help!

[image]

Comment: Hello ! For this kind of task there needs to be a way for blender to recognize your objects as groups. Do they share a naming convention ?

Comment: Hi, so this is how my outliner looks.
https://dropmefiles.com/L6qfV
I have a collection with all the furniture and construction materials, it needs to be counted from there

Comment: you can see the *total* object count (lights, cameras, "normal" objects etc.) by right clicking on the status bar and checking "scene statistics"

Comment: @Jonas, scene statistics shows total object count, not the way I described... I need count per object, as I wrote in my post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from bpy import data as D
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(int)
for ob in D.objects:
    underscore_split = ob.name.split('_')
    if len(underscore_split) < 2:
        continue
    counter[underscore_split[1].split('.')[0].strip()] += 1

for name, count in counter.items():
    print(f"{name} count: {count}")
```

The logic how to determine if an object should be counted / how to categorize it (what bucket to put it in), how to process the name string all are really more relevant to Python than Blender and you might want to ask on Stack Overflow. The Blender relevant part is just that you can iterate over `D.objects`, and each object has a `name` attribute. However, since you mention a scene, maybe you want to use `from bpy import context as C`, and `for ob in C.scene.objects:`

Comment: thanks! that works! Although it does not count everything...

Comment: @TedRyabov programming is not magic, the program has to be told what to count and how to group counted objects.

Comment: @Marus von Broady, well, that's why i'm here, asking for help...
If I need to describe more of what needs to be done, I am up for it, just ask me what to explain

Comment: @TedRyabov imagine that you hire an intern, and you ask the intern to group the objects into buckets, and then name the buckets and give you a summary of what buckets there are and how many objects are in each bucket. You're absolutely not allowed to ask anything creative of the intern: e.g. you can't say "find out something common about a group of objects and use that as a name". It is your job to precise the algorithm about naming a bucket.

Comment: In my code that algorithm is "if an object's name doesn't have an underscore, don't put it into any bucket. Otherwise take all the characters of its name up to, but not including, the first dot, strip it off whitespace (remove spaces at the beginning and end of the resulting string), and use that as the bucket name". Apparently you don't like this algorithm, so I ask you what algorithm do you want instead.

Answer (score 0):

So, I learned a little Python over the weekend and that is the solution I was looking for. @Markus von Broady, thank you for the template, that is what I came up with eventualy:

```
import bpy
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict(int)
for obj in bpy.data.collections['Stands'].all_objects:
    dot_split = obj.name.split('.')
    counter[dot_split[0].split('.')[0].strip()] += 1

for name, count in counter.items():
    print(f"{name:35} | {count:1d}")
```

here is what this code returns, what I needed it to return in the first place:

[image]

Now I want to try and write an addon which will collect this data aumatically and return into the addon window. I really have no idea how to do it, but I will keep trying and, if anyone has any useful tips, I would love to hear you out!